# How to compile assembly and C together as bin format

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I am trying to make my own operating system from scratch and am making my own boot loader. I have a function to print a string onto the screen.

Here is some code that I have:

```
ORG 0x7C00
BITS 16

mov si, msg
call Print

cli
hlt

Print:
  lodsb
  cmp al, 0
  je Done
  mov ah, 0Eh
  mov bh, 0
  int 10h
  jmp Print

Done:
  ret

msg db 'Hello World!', 0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

This is then compiled with the following command:

```
nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin
```

The question is, how would I be able to access the print function within C? I know I have to use the extern keyword, but how would I compile this into a binary format file?

Comment: Do you want to use C code in the bootloader or in your operating system? Is your operating system a 16 bit or 32 bit operating system?

Comment: @fuz I am only at the bootloader stage at the moment so am doing this to learn how to mix C and assembly together. My host OS is macOS 64bit and my operating system will be booting in real mode 16 bit.

Comment: "bin format" is often used when it really means "no format whatsoever". That makes sense for bootloaders; there's nothing yet which could interpret the format. It also means there's no real way to find `Print` from C.

Comment: @MSalters At what stage would I be able to do this then? When I load a filesystem?

Comment: @iProgram: I would say much, much earlier than that. Remember, I'm looking at some code right now that basically tries to print something **immediately** after booting.

Comment: @iProgram A bootloader is not a really good example for interaction between C and assembly because its size is restricted to 512 bytes and its in 16 bit mode (which only few compilers can generate code for).  If you are programming for 16 bit mode, I'm not quite sure which C compiler you are going to use.  gcc and clang can't generate code for that for example.

Comment: Generally though, you are going to need a linker that links the different object files together to produce a binary.  While it is possible to generate a bootsector this way, it's not really a good example to illustrate the general principle.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to run `gcc` with `-ffreestanding` (don't link) and then link using `ld` with the flags `-static`, `-nostdlib`.

Creating bootloader in C is not exactly good idea. I'd recommend you to get copy of GRUB and work on top of it. OSDEV wiki has explained this incredibly well.

To sum things up, whenever you'll try to create bootloader in C, use these to compile it:

```
$ gcc -m16 -c -g -Os -march=i686 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror -I. -o bootloader.o bootloader.c
$ ld -static -T linker.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o bootloader.elf bootloader.o
$ objcopy -O binary bootloader.elf bootloader.bin
```

Second thing, you can't use extern! You didn't set up stack, so C code will probably bail out pretty quickly. C compiler doesn't know in which format do you pass parameters to it, because your function doesn't follow any of usual conventions. Possible linker script:

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{    
    . = 0x7C00;    
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        _text = .;
        *(.text);
        _text_end = .;
    }
    .data :
    {
        _data = .;
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON)
        _data_end = .;
    }    
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)    
    {        
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }    
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.note*);
        *(.iplt*);
        *(.igot*);
        *(.rel*);
        *(.comment);  
    }
}
```

Also, GCC is by default emitting 32-bit code - you need to force it to generate 16-bit code using `__asm__(".code16gcc\n")` or, as suggested in comments, pass `-m16` parameter to compilers' commandline.

You can rewrite your function to C (to make it complain any of calling conventions) like so:

```
void print(const unsigned char * s){
        while(*s){
                __asm__ __volatile__ ("int  $0x10" : : "a"(0x0E00 | *s), "b"(7));
                s++;
        }
}
```

And of course, right after `.code16gcc`, you'd have to jump directly to your bootloader start: `__asm__ ("jmpl  $0, $main\n");`

Comment: You probably want `unsigned char`, otherwise sign-extending high-ASCII characters will set AH=0xFF.  (Also maybe worth mentioning that adapting that function for other `int 0x10` calls requires changing the constraints to account for changing AL or other output registers, unlike AH=0x0e / int 0x10.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You may be right, I'm writing this from top of my head.
Be sure to drop an edit if you'd want to improve this answer

Comment: I double-checked that `char` is signed in the ABI used by x86 gcc.  https://godbolt.org/z/wwxHBA, so signed `*s` as an operator to binary `|` would be sign-extended to `int` according to the default integer promotions.

Comment: You should probably compile with `-m16` instead of manually hacking in a  `.code16gcc`.  That might be all `-m16` does, though: I don't think it changes the ABI, or ever uses 16-bit addressing modes.

Comment: When linking, I am getting the issue `ld: unknown option: -Tlinker.ld`. What am I meant to do? I pasted the linker code in a file called `linker.ld`. Also, I don't think objcopy is for macOS and think it is Windows only?

Comment: objcopy is thing shipped with GCC

Comment: i forgot to put space between -T and linker.ld.

Comment: Now it gives me `ld: unknown option: -T`. I tried changing it to `-t` instead and then it gives me `ld: unknown option: -nostdlib`

Comment: I also don't have objcopy. `-bash: objcopy: command not found`

Comment: You are missing basic system components. Just install them :)

Comment: Also, LD has -nostdlib option: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld
Better get your hands on linux, it will save you lots of stress and time

Comment: Might it me that macOS uses clang as the compiler which wraps with gcc?

Comment: No idea, never used macOS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181306/discussion-between-iprogram-and-krzysztof-szewczyk).